# Why does the JVM use giant int[] of all 0's?

Tags: java, jvm, overhead

I know there is an intrinsic overhead of the JVM, and I wanted to do further research to see exactly what the overhead is from.

Using the YourKit profiler I was able to find that there are giant int[] filled with seemingly random information. My guess was that these store some performance metrics and other things that the JVM uses to optimize applications; but to my surprise all the elements are value `0`.

To get my results I used the following "do nothing" program, so that the results only include things happening on the JVM.

```
public final class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

}
```

This is a screenshot of the profiling result, and I can upload a memory snapshot if necessary.

[image: Screenshot from YourKit profiler]

Comment: Maybe that's why he posted this question...?

Comment: @Jire Please refrain from making substantial edits that hijack the post. In this case the OP approved it, but that is generally unacceptable.

Comment: @4castle English is not my native tongue so I appreciated his edits. Thanks for the FYI.

Comment: Calling `System.gc()` causes about 5 MB of the `int[]` to be garbage collected.

Comment: @4castle the int[] array quickly grows back to over 10mb after GCing

Comment: Seems like the objects are created only when capturing snapshot (check in generations tab).

Comment: Use allocation recording if you want to figure out where they're created

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've been playing around with this some more and it definitely has to do with the heap size. For example, if I set -Xmx5m -Xmx5m, the int array allocation is gone. Whereas if I set -Xmx5g -Xms5g it creates a lot bigger arrays.

[image]

<s>I wonder what they use them for.</s>

Got help from the /r/java.

"Most probably, those are filler objects in Thread Local Allocation Buffers that help with heap parsability: https://shipilev.net/jvm-anatomy-park/5-tlabs-and-heap-parsability/
They are supposed to be unreachable, and filtered by tools that parse heap dumps. In your screenshot, the profiler shows "All Objects (reachable and unreachable)"."

Comment: This will likely be flagged and possibly deleted soon, because it is not an answer to the question. Instead, you should edit your question and include the new information that you found.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer by examining the incoming links to those arrays. Just right-click a reachable array, select 'Selected Objects' and then switch to 'Incoming References'.

I found that there are tables in `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo`, `sun.util.Calendar.BaseCalendar`, `java.util.Currency` etc.

It's hard to tell for sure, but most likely, those large unreachable not-zeroed arrays were used by JVM to load Java byte code from .class-files. JVM doesn't need them after compilation, so they were released but haven't collected yet.

Comment: Thanks didn't know that. But my main concern is the arrays with > 600k indices which are unreachable.

Comment: I've added my thoughts on that to the answer.

Comment: They never get collected for the entire lifetime of the program which makes we wonder what they are used for. Good theory though :)